WCF SOAP service to upload documents with base64 string giving error- 413 Request Entity Too Large when hitting it from Postman for documents>50 kb
I have a WCF SOAP service to upload documents. It is working fine when debugging it locally but when hitting it from Postman, it is giving error status- 413 Request Entity Too Large for documents of size > 50 kb but working for documents size< 50 KB. We are making a Postman call with base64 string in a JSON

According to your description, your service is working fine, but you have a problem with Postman.
You can set Content-length in the header settings of the postman. I think you can set a relatively large value here to test.

